# There was a problem setting up codemirror indentUnit,

Tags: javascript

I changed the `indentUnit` of codemirror by the following code

```js
  $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        if(data.success){
          let editor_mode = $("#editor_mode option:selected").val()
          let tab_size = $("#tab_size option:selected").val()
          editor.setTabSize(tab_size)
          if (editor_mode == 'vim'){
            editor.setVimMode()
          }else{
            editor.setEmacsPrefix()
          }
          editor.fit()
          editor.autoFormatRange()
          $('#settingModal').modal('hide')
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

```js
  setTabSize(tabSize){
    this.cm.setOption('tabSize', tabSize)
    this.cm.setOption('indentUnit', tabSize)
  }
```

But after I changed, indented multiplied by 10

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, i set

```js
this.cm.setOption('tabSize',2)
this.cm.setOption('indentUnit',2)
```

Indent effect becomes 20.
If set

```js
this.cm.setOption('tabSize',4)
this.cm.setOption('indentUnit',4)
```

Indent effect becomes 40.